# Как правильно задать зависимости с помощью Dagger 2?

Tags: java, android, mvp, dagger2

Есть два класса singletone и presenter которые нужно inject'ить (один класс (`BindCityManager`) в другой (`CityListSPController`), и в presenter, сам presenter в view)

AppModule:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private Context mContext;

    public AppModule(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context provideContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

DataModule:

```
@Module
public class DataModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public BindCityManager provideBindCityManager(Context context) {
        return BindCityManager.getInstance(context);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public CityListSPController provideCityListSPController(Context context) {
        return CityListSPController.getInstance(context);
    }
}
```

DataComponent:

```
@Component (modules = {DataModule.class, AppModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface DataComponent {

    void inject(CitiesPresenter presenter);

    void inject(CityListSPController controller);
}
```

И собственно presenter:

```
public class CitiesPresenter implements CitiesContract.Presenter {

    @Inject
    BindCityManager mBindCityManager;

    @Inject
    CityListSPController mCityListSPController;

    CitiesContract.View mView;

    @Inject
    CitiesPresenter(CitiesContract.View view) {
        mView = view;
    }
```

//..other methods
    }

Модуль для Presenter

```
@Module
public class CitiesPresenterModule {

    private final CitiesContract.View mView;

    public CitiesPresenterModule(CitiesContract.View view) {mView = view;}

    @Provides
    CitiesContract.View provideCitiesContractView() {
        return mView;
    }
}
```

И компонент

```
@Component (dependencies = {DataComponent.class}, modules = CitiesPresenterModule.class)
public interface CitiesPresenterComponent {

    void inject(CitiesFragment fragment);

    CitiesPresenter getPresenter();
}
```

Во вью поступаю следущим образом:

```
public class CitiesFragment extends Fragment implements CitiesContract.View {

    @Inject
    CitiesPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cities_fragment, container, false);

        DaggerCitiesPresenterComponent.builder()
                .citiesPresenterModule(new CitiesPresenterModule(this))
                .build()
                .inject(this);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Но возникает ошибка компиляции, которую я не могу побороть:

```
Error:(5, 48) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerDataComponent

Error:(19, 54) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerCitiesPresenterComponent

Error:(9, 1) error: com.luxary_team.simpleweather.presenter.cities.CitiesPresenterComponent (unscoped) cannot depend on scoped components:
@Singleton com.luxary_team.simpleweather.controller.DataComponent

Error:(12, 10) error: com.luxary_team.simpleweather.controller.data_controllers.BindCityManager cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
com.luxary_team.simpleweather.controller.data_controllers.BindCityManager is injected at
com.luxary_team.simpleweather.presenter.cities.CitiesPresenter.mBindCityManager
com.luxary_team.simpleweather.presenter.cities.CitiesPresenter is injected at
com.luxary_team.simpleweather.ui.fragment.cities.CitiesFragment.presenter
com.luxary_team.simpleweather.ui.fragment.cities.CitiesFragment is injected at
com.luxary_team.simpleweather.presenter.cities.CitiesPresenterComponent.inject(fragment)
```

Подскажите, что я не так делал когда объявлял зависимости?

UPD. Внес некоторые поправки в класс CitiesPresenterComponent заменив аннотацию на

```
@Component (modules = {CitiesPresenterModule.class, AppModule.class, DataModule.class})
```

Теперь возникает другая ошибка

```
Error:(10, 1) error: com.luxary_team.simpleweather.presenter.cities.CitiesPresenterComponent (unscoped) may not reference scoped bindings:
@Provides @Singleton com.luxary_team.simpleweather.controller.data_controllers.BindCityManager com.luxary_team.simpleweather.controller.data_controllers.DataModule.provideBindCityManager(android.content.Context)
@Provides @Singleton android.content.Context com.luxary_team.simpleweather.AppModule.provideContext()
@Provides @Singleton com.luxary_team.simpleweather.controller.data_controllers.CityListSPController com.luxary_team.simpleweather.controller.data_controllers.DataModule.provideCityListSPController(android.content.Context)
```

Comment: Вы scope не указали для CitiesPresenterComponent. Создайте для него свой и укажите (не @Singleton).

Comment: @YuraIvanov благодарю за совет, проблемы действительно возникали из-за некорректно объявленных скоупов